# Python AsyncIO stream reader not reading properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, socket.io, python-asyncio

I have created server which reads message and the client will  write the message(which contain header
message concat with body) .However my server not reading properly, At first time reading entire message and the second time it just read the header not reading the Body.

In server.py

```
import asyncio
from _socket import AF_INET
async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(1024)
    print(data)
async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
             handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 449, family=AF_INET)
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()
asyncio.run(main())
```

In client snippet:

```
message = loadImage()
writer.write(len(json.dumps(message)).to_bytes(4, 'little') + json.dumps(message).encode("utf-8"))
await writer.drain()
```

And also checked in Wire shark same message for both client request.
both header and body length are same.

Could please help to resolve?

Comment: Shouldn't you be reading the message with two reads: the first one using `reader.readexactly(4)` and converting to length, and the second `reader.readexactly(<number obtained from first read>)`? Otherwise the rest of the data might be stuck in a stream buffer.

Comment: Also, please provide a _runnable_ (and minimal) example that reproduces the error. The provided client snippet might be missing relevant details.